# Is it okay to call `cancel()` more than once on the same Kotlin coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

According to [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancelling-coroutine-execution), calling `cancel` on a `Job` cancels the running coroutine.  Does calling `cancel` again on the same `Job` have any negative effects?  I would assume it just does nothing, and that seems to be the case in practice, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation where it makes this explicit.

**Is it safe to `cancel` an already-canceled `Job`?**

*A little explanation as to why I'm asking: I have a button that, when pressed, cancels a `Job`.  The `Job` may not stop immediately, so it is possible for the user to tap the button more than once if they tap quickly.  I need to know if I need to add code to ensure I only call `cancel` once when the button is first pressed, or if it's okay for the button to call `cancel` each time it is pressed.  I know calling `cancel` again won't make the coroutine stop any faster; I just need to know it's not going to cause problems!*

Comment: Yes cancelling an already cancelled job is safe and does nothing.

Comment: From a UI point of view, wouldn't it make sense to disable the button once pressed, to give some visual feedback that the button has been pressed and the job is being cancelled? (That would also prevent it being cancelled more than once, though according to other answers that's not necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KotlinX Coroutines `Job#cancel` is idempotent, so no matter how many times you call `cancel` it will achieve the same result.

Internally `Job` already tracks it's state, so calling `cancel` many times will not cause any issues as the `cancel` function itself will never fail, or throw an exception.

A Job can only transition from `Active` or `Completing` to `Cancelling` when calling `cancel`, so it also has no effect on the state of the internal `Job` since this transition happens atomically. If a `Job` is in the `Cancelling` or `Cancelled` state than any subsequent calls to `cancel` will be ignored.

```
                                      wait children
+-----+ start  +--------+ complete   +-------------+  finish  +-----------+
| New | -----> | Active | ---------> | Completing  | -------> | Completed |
+-----+        +--------+            +-------------+          +-----------+
                 |  cancel / fail       |
                 |     +----------------+
                 |     |
                 V     V
             +------------+                           finish  +-----------+
             | Cancelling | --------------------------------> | Cancelled |
             +------------+                                   +-----------+
```